# Difference between "heute", "heutig", and "heutigen"?

Tags: english-to-german, difference, german-to-english

I was looking up the German word for "Today's" and Google translate suggested "heutigen" but I did not see that even listed in my English to German dictionary. But I did find many instances written across various German sites.

Does "heutigen" also get used as "today's"? like "Today's news"

What are some examples of how they are properly used in a sentence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`heute` is the adverb form as in

> Heute gehen wir zum Labor (= Today we're going to the lab)

`heutig` is the adjective form that in German is used to say "today's"

> Das heutige Wetter ist schlecht (Today's weather is bad)
>
> Der heutige Mensch ist stärker als zuvor (=Today's man/person is stronger than before)

`heutigen` is declined form of "heutig"

Comment: which declension, example, otherwise perfectly answered.

Answer (score 4):

Example: "Am heutigen Sonntag gehen wir in die Kirche".  -   "On today's sunday, we are going to the church." (But I'm not sure if you can say this in English?)
"Die heutigen Nachrichten" - "Today's news"
But you don't use "heutigen" very often. In this case I'd rather say "die Nachrichten von heute"